# W3C validator returns HTTP 500, despite it works in browser

Tags: java, android, http, w3c-validation

I tried following URL:

```
http://validator.w3.org/mobile/check?docAddr=mobisoft.net.pl&output=unicorn
```

In desktop firefox or chrome browsers and all works fine. It returns valid XML response.

After that I created Android application, which connects to W3C in order to get the validation results. Code below:

```
Url url = new URL("http://validator.w3.org/mobile/check?docAddr=mobisoft.net.pl&output=unicorn"); 
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
```

I always get HTTP status code 500 INTERNAL SERVER PROBLEM, despite the fact, that it works fine, while executing the same url on the desktop browsers. The same problem for other websites.

Do you have any idea, why it does not work in my Android application?

Comment: Perhaps the URL is being mangled somehow by android before it's sent out to the server. Some escaping being done, perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried making the webrequest as described here, just in case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-in-http-request-with-android

Comment: Why are you comparing the execution of a java program on android to the result you get on a desktop browser? You're adding lots of unnecessary unknowns. Does the url work on the mobile browser? Does the program work in a normal java application on your desktop?

Comment: I tried the same URL in the Android default browser on the mobile device and it works fine.

Comment: Well then next step try it from a normal java program on the desktop :)

Comment: I tried the same code on Java desktop application and it returns HTTP status code 200.

Comment: @Graham Smith - using webrequest also returns HTTP 500 status code

Comment: Interesting so we know now that there's no general problem on the phone and that the program works just. Next guess: Security problem? Make sure the right rights are set in the manifest.

Comment: I have permission:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
I don't think that any other permission is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a HTTP "User-Agent" header, maybe that's the problem. Otherwise, I would suggest to use an existing open source Java library, which does this validation on your behalf (through W3C): [rexsl-w3c](http://www.rexsl.com/rexsl-w3c/index.html)

edit: Add "Accept" HTTP header with "application/soap+xml" value, will work fine.

Comment: I added "User-Agent" header and it does not work.
This library does not include mobileOK checker :/.

Comment: This validation will be implemented in a few days in rexsl-w3c, see: http://trac.fazend.com/rexsl/ticket/382

Comment: I edited my answer, use the "Accept" HTTP header and you'll be fine

Comment: It works with "Accept" HTTP header with "application/soap+xml".
Thank you very much yegor 256!!